# A string replacement question with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I remove string in **bold** within following url where **q=** is fixed parameter?

http://abc.com/qwe.aspx?**q=DIEYeGJgNwvPSJ32ic1sY5x1ZYjOZTQZD9mjWl2EQJ8=**&u=/foo/boo/kb

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is pretty simple. I use [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to parse the url, then remove the `q` query string parameter, and then build a new url without this parameter:

```
var url = new Uri("http://abc.com/qwe.aspx?q=DIEYeGJgNwvPSJ32ic1sY5x1ZYjOZTQZD9mjWl2EQJ8=&u=/foo/boo/kb");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);
query.Remove("q");
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(url);
ub.Query = query.ToString();
var result = ub.Uri.ToString();
```

Now `result` holds value: `http://abc.com/qwe.aspx?u=/foo/boo/kb`.

Comment: This sould be the safest way to remove the query parameter.

Comment: Too much code to do a simple thing. If the point is that url is the one found in HttpRequest, then, this could be an overkill. I'll vote for regex solution.

Comment: The regex solution mentioned below as it is written at the moment does not just match the parameter named **q** but instead all parameters that end with **q** and thus won't work as intended.

Comment: Not the simplest solution, but given the lack of context for the source of the URL, it is definitely the most correct. +1

Answer (score 1):

`input = Regex.Replace(input, "q=[^&]+", "")` would be one way to do it.

Comment: You need to be a little careful with this one since a parameter like "uq=something" will be removed unintentionally.

Comment: No it won't, "q=" won't match "qu=".

Comment: @Marius, wouldn't the `q=` part of the regex prevent that?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the parameter name (I've fixed it now). I thought of a parameter called **uq**.

Comment: @Marius, good point. If that was a possibility, we could always add a look-behind for `[?&]`.

Comment: @Zebi: Indeed, the pattern matches *q=/foo/boo/* — however, *uq=/foo/boo/* is not supposed to match!

Answer (score 0):

Are the positions fixed? You can do one `IndexOf("q=")` and `IndexOf("u=")` and use `SubString` twice to remove the part. An other way would be to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this URL comes from some request, meaning you've that query string in the HttpRequest instance, associated to HttpContext.

In this case, you can always remove "q" query string parameter just by calling `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Remove("q");`

Another solution would be the one suggested by Alex.

Answer (score -1):

if Q is a fixed parameter....

```
str = str.Replace("q=DIEYeGJgNwvPSJ32ic1sY5x1ZYjOZTQZD9mjWl2EQJ8=", "");
```

Otherwise I would do:

```
var qa = Request.QueryString;
qa.Remove("q");
var queryString = qa.ToString();
```

Comment: This is not helpful — the parameter *name* is fixed, not its value!

Comment: He said it's fixed.  Anyways, I added what I would do for a variable value query string.

Comment: The parameter name is fixed, not the string after **q=**!

Comment: @Marius Schulz, How do you know that?  He said `q= is fixed parameter` which makes me think that the parameter doesn't change.

Comment: I inferred that just the part **q=** is fixed because Ricky wrote that part in bold.